# Slider Plugin to use Single Image instead of several

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement the following slider into my website: http://simplewpthemes.com/demo/theme/?wptheme=MahasoliTribune

Now, as you can see, the slider consists of 5 images. I want to use a single image, but the image should be divided into 5 parts when displaying the non-hover state, so that the very left 'image' should focus on the left side  of the image, the 2nd 'image' should show the next part of the image, but this is all part of one image, almost like a sprite effect, where the preview (non-hover minimized state) is basically a specific part of the single original large image.

Can anyone help me on this one?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just split your big image in 5 ? You may need a custom function that would move your image rather than sliders thought and built for multi images purposes.

EDIT : as requested here is the custom js function to slide ONE image :

http://jsfiddle.net/ktNxN/ (click on the button)

Most of the magic happens here :

```
var slideView = $('.bigImage');
var slideWidth = parseInt(slideView.css('width'));
var slideStep = slideWidth/5;
```

SECOND EDIT : I realize just now what you want to achieve. Can't you just try to put divs for each panel with a different background position (where the background would be your large image)

to do this :

HTML

```
 <img src="transparent_png_1x1.png">
```

CSS

```
 img {
 /* to be sure the png covers the whole area */
 width:100%;height:100%;
 /* put your big image as the css background */
 background-image:url(bigImage.jpg);
 }

 img:nth-of-type(1) {background-position:0px 0px;}
 img:nth-of-type(2) {background-position:100px 0px;}
```

.. and so on, will need some adaptation to fill your need

Comment: thanks. But you see, it is that custom function that I'm interested in...And that would mean editing the source code (.js file), and to any-one not fluent in js, it's a bit confusing...

Comment: I'm gonna build a quick jq prototype for you, nothing violent

Comment: Thank you very much for going the extra mile, really appreciate. Yeah I see what you mean on creating the div with the background, but the original slider uses an <img /> inside the slider div, and not background images. Thus, moving the background image (with left:) will also move the enlarged image when it is expanded...Any ideas?

Comment: Answer accepted would be appreciated aswell :)

What you can try, is set a transparent png as your <img/> src and then with css, specify for each a different background-position. See the edit in my answer

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, but this also doesn't work out quite well, since the background-image preview (before hovering on it) lokks great now, but when you expand the image by hovering on it, the image is not centered anymore, and it cuts of content...I think the only way to fix that is by resetting the css position once hovering on the image...

Comment: True, you'd need to add a selector for when the image is opened, your script does add an active-like class right ? Inspect the source code while using it to know

Comment: Yes you are right, and I've been playing with it for some time now, but it does not seem to work. I tried various methods, this being one: 
$('.active img').css('background-position', '0');

Comment: I think it might be because the original css set is inline...(the css set for the img is set inline...)

Comment: Inline should be no problem, since you use jquery to apply styles, try these values $('.active img').css('background-position', 'center'); top, bottom, left, right, until you get some result. Becarefull background-position property usually takes 2 attributes left and top

Comment: Nope, does not work either...even when removing the styles as inline and using them externally